# Why are changing Zabbix's triggers status to unknown?

Tags: notifications, status, zabbix

In Zabbix I have an item which I create some triggers for that on below conditions:

1. `{Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0,1800)}>{Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0)}`
2. `{Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0,1800)}<{Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0)}`
3. `{Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.avg(900)}=0`
4. `{Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0,1800)}={Server Template:mysql.slowqueries.last(0)}`

The first one's Severity is defined as disaster. When the trigger is run its status is `UNLNOWN` in Monitoring -> Events.

What is the problem? Why is it? And how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

`UNKNOWN` status probably means that Zabbix could not calculate value of your item.
Check "Monitoring" -> "Latest data" applying the host filter.
To solve the issue you have to troubleshoot `mysql.slowqueries` items.